# Fast Report Showing Images From Database

Tags: c#, image, reporting, fastreport

Hello everyone who codes. I a working on a project that uses reporting a lot. My problem or i wanna do is: In my folder there are a lot of material images. I am showing material images according to its stock code. For example i have 200 image of my stock parts. 3 of 200 havent got image so their imageUrls are 'null'. Instead of Stock Parts that havent got image, my program shows one before parts image. So i want to do this. If a part hasnt got image , my report wont show image or will show empty white image. I dont know that am i clearly explain my problem. Here is simple code of my report page.

```
private void Picture1_BeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((String)Report.GetColumnValue("Stock_Products.ResimUrl") != null)
        Picture1.ImageLocation = ((String)Report.GetColumnValue("Stock_Products.ResimUrl"));
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the above code working or is it just an example?

Comment: I have forgotten to write return after else. Its working but it does not do my want completly

Comment: "my program shows one before parts image" what does that mean? A picture before the current one? Also, are you unable to show the white image or a white image is appearing and is the problem?

Comment: First  yes A picture before the current one i ried to say. Second It can be empty image i mean with saying white image

Comment: So you want the image before the current one to appear but a white image is appearing instead, correct? (Sorry for the stupid questions)

Comment: No just the opposite. Now image before current one appear on my screen.But this part hasnt got image file. I want white image to appear

Answer (score 0):

You can either try making a white image and saving the link to it as a const and then use that image whenever the url to the part image is null or make a new `Bitmap` object and fill it with white and use that. The first one is better imo because it's only going to take one variable in your code whilst the bitmap image is going to occupy some lines.